# How to make large numbers in column look readable (like 100B)

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, largenumber

Python 3

I have a dataframe with columns consisting of large numbers like 10,660,597,959.00.
When I plot the graph it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmFbx.png)

Is there a way to make numbers look like 10.6B instead of 10,660,597,959.00?

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Comment: @KetanYekale sorry, I forgot to mention. It's python 3

Comment: Are you using matplotlib?

Comment: @9769953 yes I am

Comment: have you looked at matplotlib documentation ?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers partially. Do you have the answer to my question?

Comment: @kirillzakharov no, sorry - I never used matplotlib actually - but 9 times out of 10 those kind of questions are answered in the doc, and you didn't mention having searched the doc without finding the answer.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I searched the answer for hours today, couldn't make it work. Perhaps it was somewhere but since I am here I do not have a solution. What do you use instead of matplotlib?

Comment: @kirillzakharov nothing, I don't have to plot data. But you should edit your post to mention what you've tried etc.

Comment: Like [this](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/custom_ticker1.html) example?

Comment: As in the linked example above, [formatters](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/ticks_and_spines/tick-formatters.html) are really good for this kind of thing. ("matplotlib formatters" was probably the missed search query.)